# need to run a .sh script in bin file in another host through cmd

Tags: ansible

I have tried this but not working.

Command that I have tried:

```
sudo -u ec2-user ssh -i {{ sso_key_path }}@{{ sso_ip_address }} "sh sso_file.sh"
```

Comment: Is `sso_file.sh` local or on the remote machine? The command you give executes it on the remote machine

Comment: it might be missing a directory. always better to use absolute paths

Answer (score 1):

Transfer the file first to the remote host and the execute it there

```
- hosts: hosts_group
  remote_user: ec2-user
  become: yes
  tasks:
    - name: transfer the script
      copy: 
       src: sso_file.sh
       dest: /tmp
       mode: 0777

    - name: execute the script
      command: sh /tmp/sso_file.sh
```